# Using Javascript to detect Temporary internet files settings

Tags: javascript

When our clients are using IE 10, we have to tell the clients to set Internet Options->Browsing History > Settings> to the option "Every time I visit the page". Is there a way in Javascript where we can detect the browser settings to warn the user if this setting is not set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.

It sounds like you should be [setting suitable cache control HTTP headers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) instead.

Comment: Thanks. The client is a flex client which I have no clue on how it works. All I know is a URL is passed to it and the component does the rest. I'll do some research.